# Tablesorter not sorting on dynamically added content

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I have a problem with Jquery Tablesorter where I am adding data dynamically to a pre-existing table.

According to the docs, after adding content, all that needs to be done is for `$("table").trigger("update")` to tbe run to tell tablesorter than new content has been added, however in reality this appears not to work.

See http://jsfiddle.net/7Wurn/9/ for an example. Clicking on the HTML table headers will order the columns, but after adding a new row  the new row does not get sorted.

It seems like something minor is wrong, as the example used on the Tablesorter website uses almost identical code to the code I've added on JSFiddle. The only difference is that the `$("table").trigger("update");` is run as part of a callback after an Ajax call.

Any ideas what is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also faced the same problem when using `datatables` in `jQuery`. When you are appending it to the `table` you are not appending the data to `same tbody element`. Instead your data is being added to a `new tbody` element. The table format should be`<thead></thead>` and then `<tbody></tbody>`.

Do something like this:

```
$("#tableId tbody").append(someContent);
```

I have updated your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7Wurn/68/. Also please use jquery 1.9.1. Its not working in 2.0b1. Don't know why

Comment: @Mottie Thanks. I saw in inspect element that a new tbody was being added everytime I add a row. But then ignored it. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

I have been playing with this and found that it's related to how, in the DOM, a tbody tag is being rendered.

I got it to work for the first entry by doing the following:

```
$("table tbody:first").before('<tr><td>Aaphod</td><td>Beeblebrox</td> <td>28</td> <td>$9.99</td> <td>20%</td><td>jul 6, 2006 8:14 am</td></tr>');
```

That's because it sticks it into the first tbody, and tablesorter recognizes it.  However, subsequent additions cause it to be inserted as a new tbody tag.

I'm going to keep playing with it and will update if I get something!